# Click button event in Unit testing is not working in Angular

Tags: angular, unit-testing, jasmine, automated-tests

I'm writing this unit test to verify when clicking back button, then it will show the login page.

The HTML script below is the back button.

```html
<button [routerLink]="[url_sep + login]" class="btn bigBtn btn-gray" keep-width type="button">
          Back
</button>
```

The script below is the unit test which I want to execute.

```
let de: DebugElement;
let el: HTMLElement;

it('should open login page when click back button', () => {
    de = fixture.debugElement.query(By.css('.btn-gray'));
    el = de.nativeElement;
    el.click();
    const compiled = fixture.debugElement.nativeElement;
    expect(compiled.querySelector('p').textContent).toContain('Welcome');
  });
```

After I ran this unit test, the button wasn't clicked, because it verified 'Welcome' word in the same page not in the log in page.

Answer (score 3):

The click event probably isn't ready yet, so you have to wait for it.
You can use `fixture.whenStable()` for this.

See the following example:

```js
it('should', async(() => {


  let button = fixture.debugElement.query(By.css('.btn-gray'));
  button.click();

  fixture.whenStable().then(() => {
    const compiled = fixture.debugElement.nativeElement;
    expect(compiled.querySelector('p').textContent).toContain('Welcome');
  });
}));
```

See [Angular Docs on testing](https://angular.io/guide/testing).

Comment: I got SyntaxError if I use querySelector. However, the button still isn't clicked, after I use fixture.whenStable().

Comment: Updated the code sample with the correct QuerySelector

Answer (score 1):

I would prefer using the method provided by the `DebugElement` to invoke the event instead of calling it directly on the native element. But either way, it is important to once wait until the event is handled and then call a fixture.detectChanges() in order to update the template to assert new rendered elements.

So it would be something like this:

```
it('should open login page when click back button', fakeAsync(() => {
    de = fixture.debugElement.query(By.css('.btn-gray'));
    el = de.triggerEventHandler('click', null);

    tick(); // this is important
    fixture.detectChanges(); // this is important

    const compiled = fixture.debugElement.nativeElement;
    expect(compiled.querySelector('p').textContent).toContain('Welcome');
  }));
```

Comment: The button still isn't click, after I use tick();  fixture.detectChanges(); and fakeAsync.

Comment: Ah yes. I see. Your button doesn‘t have a click listener at all. So it does nothing on click. What are you trying to test? The routing?